# Read/Write ConnectionString in app.config

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a form in wpf for connection string change on all client machines.

Wpf application is accessing connection string from myprogram.exe.config rather than app.config. Whenever i am deleting myprogram.exe.config and trying to run myprogram.exe it's not loading/running.

how can I fix this issue and how i can access connection string from app.config rather than myprogram.exe.config?

Comment: _myprogram.exe.config_ is compiled variant of _app.config_ form your project

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks for your response. so if i want to change connection string on client computer. I have to change it in myprogram.exe.config ?

Comment: That is right!!

Comment: Exactly. Or update it in _app.config_ and than recompile your app

Comment: how to update in in app.config please guide

Comment: You update it like you have updated it so far. Then you just build/publish your app again. The new value will be there when it transforms into myprogram.exe.config.

Comment: what i want it to get connection string from app.config rather than from myprogram.exe.config

Comment: myprogram.exe.config is the configuration file that your app uses *at runtime*. What's the difference between this one and the app.config file in your source code project that is used at *compile* time? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My program is not loading when i am changing connection string from local computer to remote server in myprogram.exe.config in client machine

Answer (score 1):

on c# after build app.config changed to exe.config 
you can look this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KdqdWTNO7Q